# How to remove MySQL completely with config and library files?

Tags: gnome, mysql

I tried everything till now:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and even more commands...

But whenever I am trying to locate mysql. I get a no. of files related to mysql

command:

```
shell>> locate mysql
```

Output:

```
/etc/mysql
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld-akonadi
/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
/etc/bash_completion.d/mysqladmin
/etc/init/mysql.conf
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.paranoid/mysql-server-5_5
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/mysql-server-5_5
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation/mysql-server-5_5
/etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server
/etc/mysql/conf.d
/etc/mysql/debian-start
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
/home/pkr/.mysql_history
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/piston-helper/rec.ubuntu.com,api,1.0,recommend_app,libqt4-sql-mysql,,349051c3a57da571aa832adb39177aff
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/piston-helper/rec.ubuntu.com,api,1.0,recommend_app,mysql-client,,cbf77a486cdc80547317981a33144427
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/piston-helper/rec.ubuntu.com,api,1.0,recommend_app,mysql-client,,de8220dee4d957a9502caa79e8d2fdda
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,any,any,any,libqt4-sql-mysql,page,1,helpful,,17fb2e657321dc51526ee8fe9928da30
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,any,any,any,mysql-client,page,1,helpful,,a4c1b6e8200f36ab5745c6f81f14da0a
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,oneiric,any,libqt4-sql-mysql,page,1,helpful,,c54295fb82b8183350cd34f22c3547ef
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,oneiric,any,mysql-client,page,1,helpful,,fcf201c1abff3f774af89173a84de2cc
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,precise,any,libqt4-sql-mysql,page,1,helpful,,0cd86648584efeccfb16119012f89540
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,precise,any,mysql-client,page,1,helpful,,eb84724e9da7851ff8862a227d8bac59
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql.err
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql.err.old
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/columns_priv.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/columns_priv.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/columns_priv.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/db.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/db.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/db.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/event.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/event.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/event.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/func.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/func.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/func.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/general_log.CSM
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/general_log.CSV
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/general_log.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_category.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_category.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_category.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_keyword.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_keyword.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_keyword.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_relation.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_relation.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_relation.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_topic.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_topic.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_topic.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/host.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/host.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/host.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/ndb_binlog_index.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/ndb_binlog_index.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/ndb_binlog_index.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/plugin.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/plugin.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/plugin.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proc.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proc.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proc.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/procs_priv.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/procs_priv.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/procs_priv.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proxies_priv.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proxies_priv.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proxies_priv.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/servers.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/servers.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/servers.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/slow_log.CSM
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/slow_log.CSV
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/slow_log.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/tables_priv.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/tables_priv.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/tables_priv.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_leap_second.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_leap_second.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_leap_second.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_name.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_name.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_name.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition_type.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition_type.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition_type.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/user.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/user.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/user.frm
/usr/bin/mysql
/usr/bin/mysql_install_db
/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade
/usr/bin/mysqlcheck
/usr/sbin/mysqld
/usr/share/mysql
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gmysqlcc:gmysqlcc.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mysql-client.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mysql-navigator:mysql-navigator.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mysql-server.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/gmysqlcc-32.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/mysql-navigator.png
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-core-5.5
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-core-5.5
/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax/sql-mysql.xml
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_install_db.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_upgrade.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlcheck.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/mysqld.8.gz
/var/cache/apt/archives/akonadi-backend-mysql_1.7.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient-dev_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libqt4-sql-mysql_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_all.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-client-core-5.5.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-client-core-5.5.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-core-5.5.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-core-5.5.md5sums
/var/log/mysql
/var/log/mysql.err
/var/log/mysql.log
/var/log/mysql.log.1.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.2.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.3.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.4.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.5.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.6.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.7.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.1.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.2.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.3.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.4.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.5.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.6.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.7.gz
```

What should I do now?

Please help me out in this :(

I was trying to find out if there is any way I can remove mysql related every file and then reinstall mysql. I need it for Qt connectivity. I don't understand what to do! Please help :(

Answer (score 3):

`locate` reads the files from a database. So whenever you delete a file from the filesystem, `locate` will still find the file, because the database was not updated.

So to update the `locate` database, run `updatedb`.

Anyway, I assume that most of the files are not there any longer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
dpkg -S /path/to/file
```

to see which package provides a file...

Answer (score -1):

for mysql-server-5.7.18

The first step is to remove the dependency which disallows the removal of MySQL packages.

```
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```