# How can I completely remove MySQL, including config and data?

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql, uninstall

On a fresh Ubuntu install, I set a root password but forgot to save it.

As I want to document the setup steps for later reproduction, I do not want to go through any password recovery steps but remove all traces of MySQL on the system and start over.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

(as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/912173/149408)), and an additional

```
rm -r /etc/mysql
```

but when I install MySQL after that, I still do not get a password prompt, which indicates there are still some MySQL leftovers from which the old password is resurrected.

How do I completely eradicate MySQL from this system, so the next MySQL install will appear like a fresh install and prompt me for a root password again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the above commands (no guarantee all of them are in fact needed), do

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mysql
```

Users and passwords (including the root password) are stored in the database itself, and the default data dir is `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: purge "should" already do this for you, at least in newer distros :)